# PyQt GUI: how to store data (class objects)?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreewidget

I recently started programming python and coded my first GUI for the post-processing and evaluation of NMR data using PyQt. The current version of the app looks like this:
[image: screenshot of the pyqt app]

The typical workflow is:

1. read data of various experiments (usually 3D or 4D (2D/3D + time/frequency) image stacks)
2. do some post processing like defining regions of interest (ROI), fitting of the time/frequency resolved spectra, calculation of contrasts and so on
3. visualize the results in the GUI
4. export the results in form of images/plots/tables with fit results(xml)
5. save the workspace to be able to reload it

The 4d image stacks are stored together with the experimental settings, image reconstuction settings, fit results etc as class objects of my own MriData class:

```
class MriData:
   def __init__(self, path='', exp_num=0, exp_name=''):
       self.path = path
       self.exp_num = exp_num
       self.exp_name = exp_name    
       self.img_stack = np.array([])
       self.ROIs = []  # list of ROIs  
       self.settings= {}
       self.lmfit = {}
       ...
```

At the moment my MainWindow has an attribute "mri_data" of type list, where I store all the data/class objects. If I select (multiple) experiments and or ROIs in the QTreeWidget on the left side, I always check if the item is a top level item or not, get the index of the experiment (and the index of the ROI if it is one) and than access the corresponding list entry in the "mri_data" list:

```
list_items: = self.QTreeWidget.selectedItems()
list_idx = self.QTreeWidget.selectedIndexes()
list_zipped = zip(list_idx, list_items)
for (index, item) in list_zipped:
    if not item.parent():  # if current item is exp
        data = self.mri_data[index.row()]
    else:  # if current item is ROI
        idx_parent = self.QTreeWidget.indexFromItem(item.parent())
        data = self.QTreeWidget[idx_parent.row()].ROIs[index.row()]
```

This works but it is obviously not so great and I'm quite sure it is very inefficient. Thats why I write this post. I read that I can store data in the QTreeWidgetItems, but before I rewrite my whole code I wanted to ask the experts if this is a good idea. I couldn't find any information about the performance if the stored data are quite big (the 4d stacks are up to 256x256x32x2500 and I have up to several hundred experiments in the QTreeWidget at the same time). Or maybe it is better to use a completely different database approach? Unfortunately, it is (at least for me) very difficult to find tutorials or posts about similar problems... maybe because I use the wrong key words?!

Thanks in advance for your answers/tips/links etc

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but i really like your gui. Do you have details on which library you used specifically for the plots? it doesnot look like other pyqt stuff i've seen

Comment: @will.mendil I am using matplotlib and the integrated backends for the visualization. The GUI is not maintained very well because I am barely using it, but I am willing to invite you to the private GitHub repo in case you are interested.

Comment: I'm currently using dearpygui but I'm interested in pyqt. I'd like to look at the code. I don't think I'll be actively contributing, but if you're about to archive the project, that'd be cool. https://github.com/willmendil

Answer (score 2):

I tested the implementation where I store data in the `QTreeWidgetItems` for quite a long time now and at least in my case it works like a charm. For example adding new items is very comfortable:

```
def add_dataset(self, _obj):
    """adds new QTreeWidgetItem when 'addItemSignal' is emitted from ImportDataDialog"""
    tree_obj = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([_obj.name])
    tree_obj.setData(1, QtCore.Qt.UserRole, _obj)
    self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(tree_obj)
```

The best thing for me, however, is the very easy and elegant way to save/load workspaces using `QDataStream`:

```
def action_saveworkspace_triggered(self, filename):
    """Saves current workspace to the selected file"""
    file = QtCore.QFile(filename)
    file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    datastream = QtCore.QDataStream(file)
    root_item = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()

    # write the total number of items to be stored
    datastream.writeUInt32(root_item.childCount())

    # write all data (= all elements of the TreeWidget) to the file
    for n in range(root_item.childCount()):
        item = root_item.child(n)
        item.write(datastream)
```

This is the corresponding load function (I hope it works; my save/load functions are actually bit more advanced):

```
def action_loadworkspace_triggered(self, filename):
    """Loads workspace from file"""

    # open the file and create datastream
    file = QtCore.QFile(filename)
    file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
    datastream = QtCore.QDataStream(file)
    root_item = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()

    # read all data from the file and create a TreeWidgetItem for each entry
    for n in range(datastream.readUInt32()):
        item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(root_item)
        item.read(datastream)
        data = item.data(1, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
```

I'm still not sure if this is the most efficient way, but at least for my application I don't suffer from any performance problems etc.

Comment: My save/load functions are actually a bit more complicated because if have several children with even more children, but I added a basic load workspace function to my answer!

Comment: Thanks. I arrived at a similar solution as I was using QTreeView + QStandardItems. It's important to note that children need to be stored separately and are not automatically bundled with the parent, this was not very intuitive.